# Can a single token built on Ethereum’s blockchain be more valuable than Ethereum itself?

Tags: ether, economics

As in the question, from an economics point of view, is it possible to ever have a single token (REP/BAT or something completely unforeseen currently) takeover the underlying's platform market cap or the network economics of the matter will always make it so the platform(ETH) that said token is built on to have more value (given it facilitates said token plus all other tokens)?

If there is any research done on this, I would be grateful to be pointed that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any reason for this to not be possible. It's simply a matter of supply and demand.

But the tokens would need to be bought with some other asset than Ethers - if you could only buy the tokens with Ethers there would be no way for the tokens to be more valuable than Ether as you'd run out of Ether before the value surpasses that of Ethers. Then the question becomes about how the tokens can be valued as it may become difficult to establish proper price for them in any automatic means: how to know how many BTC/fiat/whatever somebody paid for a token as the transaction is not recorded in Ethereum blockchain (except the token transfer).

Comment: Thank you, Lauri, this puts my mind in a train of thought to ponder on.